# Colab upgraded to TensorFlow 2.0, now am experiencing an error RuntimeError: version does not support TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have been running my DL models on colab well, until they upgraded the system last Friday.
I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _get_default_graph()
     65     try:
---> 66         return tf.get_default_graph()
     67     except AttributeError:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _get_default_graph()
     67     except AttributeError:
     68         raise RuntimeError(
---> 69             'It looks like you are trying to use '
     70             'a version of multi-backend Keras that '
     71             'does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend '
```

> RuntimeError: It looks like you are trying to use a version of multi-backend Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend using `tf.keras`, or alternatively, downgrading to TensorFlow 1.14.

I am currently running Python 3.7.6 version on my Mac(Mojave).
I am running TensorFlow 2.0.0 version on my machine.

Comment: Well, the error is quite clear, you need to upgrade keras to a version that supports TF 2.0 (like Keras 2.3.1) or use tf.keras

Comment: my current Keras version is 2.3.1...that would appear to be the updated version for TF 2.0

Comment: What I find odd though is that my Python version is 3.7.6 but if you look at the error above it mentions version 3.6.

Comment: The python version in Colab has nothing to do with the version in your local machine. Are you sure your Colab instance is running Keras 2.3.1?

Comment: yes, I checked both python and Keras versions on my terminal.

Comment: here's another kicker: I can run(just finished running) image classification neural network using colab. but when I tried again the face detection(am using MTCNN module) it gives me the above error

Comment: what is the output of this `import keras; print(keras.__version__)` on your Colab?

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue while using the Google Colab. 
So what I did was, imported all the modules from the tensorflow.keras modules, instead of using the traditional method of calling via keras only.

eg. instead of 
 `from keras.models import Sequential` 
 
use

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
```

And, 
`from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout`
 use

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
```

So, my new code looks like this. [My new code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qarz.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try using from *tensorflow.keras.models* import Model

And make sure that all the Keras modules imported are of the same version.
Don't use
***`from tensorflow.keras.models import Model`*** 
and 
***`from Keras import layers`***, 
while building NN in the same notebook else it keeps on throwing some errors.

This solution helped me.